# How to force counting page numbers from a particular page

Tags: page-numbering

Let us consider the following scenario.

This is the partial code in the main.tex file and which includes code from other tex files like acknowledgements.tex,certificate.tex, abstract.tex etc.,

```
  ....................
  \include{certificate}
  \include{abstract}
  \include{introduction}
  \include{Chap1}
  \include{Chap2}
  ...................
```

Now let my PDF counting page numbers from certificate, but I want to count the page numbers from chap1.

Is it possible to force counting from a particular page.

Note: There may be counting for certificate,abstract and introduction too, but from chap1 counting has to start from 1. It is good if there is no counting before chap1.

Comment: dome document classes define `\frontmatter` (which numbers pages with roman numerals) and `\mainmatter` (which restarts counting with page 1, and uses arabic page numerals).  if the document class you use (you didn't identify it) does this, you can place `\frontmatter` right after `\begin{document}` and `\mainmatter` immediately before `\include{Chap1}`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Yeah, its worked.
Is this question worth enough to ask here, If not I will delete before some one answer. Otherwise down votes will happen.

Comment: no, don't delete it -- it might help someone else.  but i think the answer to this question is close enough that it can be pointed to as a duplicate: [Start TOC from chapter 1 and also page numbering](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/226864/579)